# Web.py routing when added nginx as upstream

Tags: python, nginx, proxy, web.py

I've been writing a client side app and a server side app as two separate apps and I want the client to use the server. The client is written in javascript and the server is written in python using web.py as the engine to deliver to the client. The client and server must be on the same web domain.

The server part has a route defined as:

```
'/data/(.*)', 'applicationserver.routes.Data.Data'
```

This works fine running it locally using `http://buildserver/data/transform`

I'm setting it up as a site in nginx like this:

```
upstream app {
  server 127.0.0.1:8081
}
```

and adding it to the web application like this:

```
location /server {
    ...
    proxy_pass 
}
```

The new path to the route would be `` ` but for obvious reasons this will not work as the server app is listening for ``/data`and not`/server/data`.

I have tried to change the route in python to `(.*)/data/(.*)` which sort of works except that it throws the error:

```
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'> at /data/transform
GET() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was going on just before posting but I hope I can help someone else by posting this anyway.

web.py is sending the matched group to the GET and therefor using `(.*)/data/(.*)` sent both the start and the end of the path to the GET which is why it failed.

Setting the route to `.*/data/(.*)` gave me what I was after and only sent the part after data to the GET function.